# How to pass multiple docker images through values.yml to template.yml in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to run a application that has around 40 microservices. How to pass 40 different docker images from values.yml file to template.yml file.

### template file

```
      name:{{ .values.name }}
spec:
   containers:
      - image: {{ .values.container.image }}
```

**values file**

```
name:A
 container:
     image:A
name :B
  container :
       image:B
```

i have 40 more docker images like that, how to pass all those images to template.
And will passing like that creates **40 different** pods?, because we would need 40 different pods.
Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this thread: [StackOverflow: How can I iteratively created pods from list using helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024074/how-can-i-iteratively-create-pods-from-list-using-helm)? Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: i had a look at it before posting the question...dint really help my case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Focusing only on images and templates** you can create a helm template that will spawn an X amount of pods by:

- Creating a `Chart.yaml` file
- Creating a `values.yaml` file with the variable that store all image names
- Creating a template with a `{{ range }}` directive
- Testing

Below is the structure of files and directories:

```sh
❯ tree helm-dir
helm-dir
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   └── pod.yaml
└── values.yaml

1 directory, 3 files
```

---

### Create `Chart.yaml` file

Below is the `Chart.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: helm-templates
description: A Helm chart for spawning pods from images
version: 0.1.0
```

---

### Create a `values.yaml` file with the variable that store all image names

Below is the simple `values.yaml` file with different images name that will be used with a template:

```yaml
different_images: 
  - ubuntu 
  - nginx
```

---

### Create a template that with a `{{ range }}` directive

This template is stored in `templates` directory with a name `pod.yaml`

Below `YAML` definition will be a template for all the pods:

```yaml
{{- range .Values.different_images }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: {{ . }} 
  labels:
    app: {{ . }} 
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: {{ . }} 
    image: {{ . }} 
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: 
    - sleep 
    - infinity
---
{{- end }}
```

`{{- range .Values.different_images }}` will iterate over `different_images` variable and  replace the `{{ . }}` with an image name.

---

### Test

Run below command from `helm-dir` directory to check if helm `YAML` definitions of pods are correctly created:

`$ helm install NAME . --dry-run --debug`

You should get an output with multiple pods definition that look similar to one below:

```yaml
# Source: helm-templates/templates/pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
  labels:
    app: ubuntu
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
    image: ubuntu
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: 
    - sleep 
    - infinity
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 500Mi
        cpu: 500m
```

You can now run: 
`$ helm install NAME .`

and check if pods spawned correctly with `$ kubectl get pods`:

```sh
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx    1/1     Running   0          8s
ubuntu   1/1     Running   0          8s
```

Please take a look on additional resources:

- [Helm.sh: Chart best practices](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/)
- [Helm.sh: Chart template guide: Control structures](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)
- [Stackoverflow.com: How can I iteratively create pods from list using helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024074/how-can-i-iteratively-create-pods-from-list-using-helm)