# Helm - Few deployments in a loop

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

i have a list of customer ids that i want to pass to the values.yml in the helm chart , and then for each customer create a deployment is that possible? this is what i want to pass in values.yml:

```yaml
customer:
  - 62
  - 63
```

and this is my deployment template
https://gist.github.com/JacobAmar/8c45e98f9c34bfd662b9fd11a534b9d5

im getting this error when im installing the chart
"parse error at (clientmodule/templates/deployment.yaml:51): unexpected EOF"

also i want to pass that customer id to the default command in the container , thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok , so i found a solution to to why helm is only creating a deployment for my last item in the list , helm uses "---" as a seprator between the specification of your yaml. so now my template looks like this and it works :)

```
    {{ range .Values.customer.id  }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "clientmodule-customer-{{ . }}"
  labels:
    {{- include "clientmodule.labels" $ | nindent 4 }}
    customer: "{{ . }}"
spec:
  {{- if not $.Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ $.Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "clientmodule.selectorLabels" $ | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with $.Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "clientmodule.selectorLabels" $ | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with $.Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "clientmodule.serviceAccountName" $ }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml $.Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: clientmodule-customer-{{ . }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml $.Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ $.Values.image.repository }}:{{ $.Values.image.tag | default $.Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ $.Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: ["sh","-c",{{$.Values.command}}]
          resources:
            {{- toYaml $.Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with $.Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with $.Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with $.Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
```

you can refer to this answer too : [looping over helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024074/how-can-i-iteratively-create-pods-from-list-using-helm/51025501)

Comment: After wasting an hour, this worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

After you entered `range`, you should be passing chart scope with `$`, for example `$.Values.podAnnotations`.

More info in [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action)

```yaml
{{ range .Values.customer  }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "clientmodule-customer-{{ . }}"
  labels:
    {{- include "clientmodule.labels" $ | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not $.Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ $.Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "clientmodule.selectorLabels" $ | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with $.Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "clientmodule.selectorLabels" $ | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with $.Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "clientmodule.serviceAccountName" $ }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml $.Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ $.Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml $.Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ $.Values.image.repository }}:{{ $.Values.image.tag | default $.Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ $.Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: ["sh","-c",{{$.Values.command}}]
          resources:
            {{- toYaml $.Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with $.Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with $.Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with $.Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but im only getting a deployment of the last item in the list, for example:
customer:
  - 65
  - 60
  - 62
  - 63
the the deployment is only generated for number 63, this could be a bug?